# Compare datetime values in django models

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I have an Offer model that has a `DateTimeField` named `offerDate` and I have two records in the database

```
>>> oldOffer.offerDate
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 29, 15, 19, 43, 755325)
>>> currOffer.offerDate
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 29, 15, 20, 2, 456100)
>>> Offer.objects.filter(offerDate__lt= currOffer.offerDate)
<QuerySet []>
>>> Offer.objects.filter(offerDate__gt= currOffer.offerDate)
<QuerySet [<Offer: Offer object (5)>, <Offer: Offer object (6)>]>
```

The `currOffer.offerDate` is clearly greater than the `oldOffer.OfferDate`. Then why am I getting an empty result with the `__lt` clause? Also why do I get both the oldOffer (object 5) and currOffer (object 6) when I use `__gt` clause? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you print `offer object (5)` and `offer object (6)` to ensure that they are what you think?!

Comment: And are you sure that `offerDate` is a `DateTimeField`?! I think maybe it's `DateField` instead!

Comment: You are right. I had change the field from DateField to DateTimeField and didn't refresh my shell models. Now I am getting correct results. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of `oldOffer.offerDate` and `currOffer.offerDate` differ in `Time` and are equal in `Date`. According to the this point and the result you are getting, you may have used `DateField` instead of `DateTimeField` and the only effective part of `currOffer.offerDate` in comparison, is its `Date`.

Comment: Yes. I was using the DateField and the comparison was happening only for the date part. Thanks for the explanation.